# I comitted Shirk on accident. Will Allah still forgive me?

Tags: allah, sin

I am 13 years old and a girl.

I had accidentally committed shirk last month and I started worrying because it is an unforgivable sin. I sincerely regret my actions and I wish I could change my past.

I told my friend about how I had accidentally committed shirk and she said that it was okay. She said that shirk is unforgivable if you believe in shirk for your whole life. She said that if you have comitted shirk and you regret it and ask Allah for forgiveness straight away, Allah will forgive you.

I started to learn how to pray and I'm also learning a dua for forgiveness.

Will Allah still forgive me from shirk or am I doomed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Allah forgive me for doing X ? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71337/will-allah-forgive-me-for-doing-x-reference-question)

Answer (score 1):

No you aren’t doomed. What your friend said is right, Allah will forgive you if you repent because Allah is the most merciful and he forgives all sins when you repent, but when you die, he only doesn’t forgive one sin : shirk.

So if you die a mushrik (or mushrika) you will go to hell forever. But if you repent sincerely of shirk you will no go to hell because of having committed shirk.

Allah is Al-Ghafur Ar-Rahim At-Tawab which means He is the Merciful, the forgiving One and the Compassionate.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend has spoken the truth.

Take the example of Quraysh. They were polytheists who associated & worshipped several false gods with Allah. When they repented, Allah forgave them.

Even Abu Sufyan, who was the chief of Quraysh and a big enemy of Prophet Muhammed and Islam, was forgiven when he repented after the conquest of Makkah by the Muslims.

But if you still feel guilty, ask forgiveness from Allah with a sincere heart and have faith that He will forgive you. Allah is Merciful. He forgives even a major sin like shirk ***if one repents before death***.

I also invite you to learn more about our beautiful religion as it is not as strict as you feel it is.

Answer (score 0):

Shirk is worshiping a deity or a spirit, willingly. Saying some inadequate words or doing something that somehow has pagan origins is not shirk - just a sin. God will forgive all you do unintentionally if you ask Him for forgiveness.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not doomed. With regard to shirk, the Holy Prophet said, " The thing I fear most for you is minor shirk." and also said, " Shirk among you is more subtle than the sound of ants on a rock. Shall I not tell you of something which, if you do it, it will take that away from you, both major and minor forms. Say: Allahumma inni a'oodha bika an ushrika bika wa'ana a'lam wastaghfiruka lima laa a'lam.

Answer (score -1):

In the name of Allah
Saying bad things about Allah because of anger or .... is not shirk but a sin. Btw please be aware that telling your friends about sins is forbidden.